# More line in console output of VS2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, console

When I run my program in VS2010,
because my output quite a lot,the console just discards my previous output.

For example, consider my output to be of 400 lines, lines 1 to 80 are not displayed, only lines 81 to 400 are displayed.

Any idea of how I can see the entire output?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can change the buffering settings of the console:  right click the title bar of the console window and select "Properties."  On the "Layout" tab, change the "Height" of the Screen Buffer to some large number (9999, for example).

Run your program again.

Of course, if you have a large amount of output that you need to inspect on a regular basis, it's probably best to write to a file instead.

Comment: James, I've VS2017, and this method has not worked once for me. It feels like the VS console is completely distinct from CMD prompt. Any changes I do to actual cmd console does not affect VS console output. Whence VS console has not the attributes like `layout` like its cousin cmd has.

Answer (score 10):

```
Console.BufferHeight = x;
Console.BufferWidth = x;
```

Sets the height and width of the console buffer.

Comment: Where should I enter this?

Answer (score 0):

Right before your output. 
You can set it dynamically based on output but be sure to remember that if a line is longer than the width you will have additional lines to contend with.