# How to print more lines from text file in console?

Tags: c#, printing, console

Currently my program is only printing the last 274 lines from the text file. How can I print the whole text file (about 500 lines) on the console?

Below is my code:

```
using System;

namespace InsertTextFileSample
{

  class Program
  {

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Example #2
        // Read each line of the file into a string array. Each element
        // of the array is one line of the file.
        string TextFile = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Firzanah\Downloads\"+TextFile);

        // Display the file contents by using a foreach loop.
        System.Console.WriteLine("Contents of nvram.txt = /n");
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            // Use a tab to indent each line of the file.
            Console.WriteLine("\t" + line);
        }

        // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

[Edit]: Found the solution here: [More line in console output of VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624895/more-line-in-console-output-of-vs2010)

Comment: It prints all lines. Why do you think it doesn't? Because your console's scroll back is not large enough to show all?

Comment: I checked the length difference of the message displayed in console and in the text file itself. That's when I noticed that only the last 274 lines are shown on the console. 

How can I enable my scroll back to show all?

Answer (score -1):

Using `File.ReadAllLines` reads the lines into an array at once. Try to read the file line-by-line:

```
using System;

namespace InsertTextFileSample
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string TextFile = Console.ReadLine();
            string path = @"C:\Users\Firzanah\Downloads\" + TextFile;
            string line;
            var fileReader =
               new System.IO.StreamReader(path);

            Console.WriteLine("Contents of nvram.txt = /n");
            while ((line = fileReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t" + line);
            }

            fileReader.Close();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the codes above but it keeps giving me errors:
1) 'string' doesn't contain a definition for 'ReadLine'
2) 'string' doesn't contain a definition for 'Close'

Comment: You have probably missed something here. I updated the whole code and changed some names. It should work for you. I tested. No errors here.

Comment: This answer is not materially different from the original code. Both will read each line from the file and both will print each of those lines to the console. So this answer doesn't in any way address the OP's actual question. The real answer is that their console window's line buffer isn't large enough to store all of the output, and so the lines except the 274 at the end have all scrolled off the top of the window's buffer by the time the program ends. Which is explained in the marked duplicate (it's not really even a programming question...it's more of a PC user question).