# Setting Visual Studio terminal output lines more than 9999

Tags: visual-studio

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5624927/10027592) answer, one can set the number of terminal output lines in Visual Studio to a maximum of 9999:

> right click the title bar of the console window and select "Properties." On the "Layout" tab, change the "Height" of the Screen Buffer to some large number (9999, for example).

However, it has been more than 10 years since that answer was written.
Is there a way to print more than this?

Comment: now why would you want to print more than 9999 lines?

Comment: @MitchWheat Simply because the output I'm printing is more than that. Writing to a file could be another way, but I was just wondering if there is a simpler way.

Comment: and are you regularly  reading through 9999+ lines of output?  (rhetorical question) .....

Comment: @MitchWheat Ah, no I don't :) I just wanted to skim through the whole output quickly. If there's no way, it's okay, I just wanted to know if there was any change since the answer I quoted.

Comment: so rather than scanning 9999+ lines, send what you want to a specific log file. I use NLog https://nlog-project.org/

Comment: @MitchWheat Thanks. I'm currently not on the .NET environment, but I'll check it out.